# ASPX..Renamed a library..now error

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

One of my websites references a library in my solution called "Foo"
That project generates a file called "Foo.dll" and the classes in it are in a namespace called "MyCompany.Foo"

so far everything worked out...well I right clicked on project "Foo" and changed the filename it outputs to to be "MyCompany.Foo"....now the project generates a file "MyCompany.Foo.dll"
everything still compiles ok but when I try to access my site it says it can't find the reference or file "Foo"

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the following specific parse error
>   details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Foo' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind it was my own stupidity.

In my web.config, I had a reference to Foo that I needed to change to MyCompany.Foo

I did a global search for Foo.dll...but in this case the assembly was referenced w/o the dll on the end

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things.

Open visual studio and your solution file. Then type ctrl+f and search for Foo.dll in ALL solution. Replace any occurences of Foo.dll with MyCompany.Foo.dll

hope this helps.

edit: In case you changed the namespaces in foo.dll from namespace foo to namespace MyCompany.Foo then you might need to make additional changes but i guess you won't need.

Also, make sure that in your ASP.NET project, the reference entry has Copy Local property set to True.